# start windows store app automatically during system restart?

Tags: windows-store-apps, window, windows-server-2012-r2

I am system admin and wondering if there is a way to start windows store app automatically during system restart? Using Window Server 2012 R2 64 bit. Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a uri launch protocol and launch the app by this protocol.. this is the only way I see in this situation.

See more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation

**UPDATE:**

Now for launching that automatically, use `start` command, this command allow us to start modern apps (Windows Store Apps).. for example, this will launch the store @ home page:

```
start ms-windows-store://home
```

In real scenario:
create .cmd file and write your command name (Your app protocol) and move this file to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Thanks Nasser, vote up, great idea. But how to skip user interactions?

Comment: Thanks Nasser, 1. in your solution of `start ms-windows-store://home`, it only start the app, if the app has user interaction, the user interaction cannot be skipped? 2. Wondering if we could have a windows store app without user interaction? So that we can put it into start menu and keep it running when system restarts?

Comment: Thanks for all the help Nasser, mark your reply as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same a few weeks ago but for now is not supported. please read this answer [UWP app start automatically at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup)

Comment: Thanks RicardoPons, vote up. Have you read reply from Nasser? It seems possible to resolve this problem by put it into start-up folder?

Comment: that only works for Win32 apps I tried that before without success

Comment: actually the app launch but is not possible without user interaction

Comment: what do you mean Win32 app? Not Windows store app?

Comment: For your comments, "the app launch but is not possible without user interaction", you said it is launched, but not possible? Seems conflict, what do you mean exactly? Thanks. :)

Comment: classic apps(Desktop apps, Windows forms,wpf) launch modern apps(uwp) automatically without user interaction is not supported

Comment: Thanks RicardoPons, you mean leveraging classic app to launch UMP? In my case, I do not have classic app, and I only have UMP. Possible to start UMP automatically through the solution of start-up folder? Thanks.

Comment: I tried that you said of start-up folder without success