# StartupTask class is not recognized

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to get my Centennial application to autostart on logon. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup/39646263#39646263)  that can be done. But then to disable it programmatically I'd need to use the [Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask) class and Visual Studio refuses to recognize it. So how is that class used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the Desktop Extension SDK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now at next hurdle: [This application can only run in the context of an app container.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860740/error-this-application-can-only-run-in-the-context-of-an-app-container).

Comment: Do you want to start a new question for this? Please include the StartupTask extension snippet from the appxmanifest and whether or not you are using .NET for your task.

Comment: My previous comment includes a link. It's my new question. And I now added the snippet there.

Comment: Got it, added a comment to your new question with a suggestion that I believe will fix it. Please give it a try.

Comment: This does, indeed, allow using the `StartupTask` class. however, that's only in the UWP part of the app. How would I use it in the .net part of the app, since that reference is not available for it? (I'm converting the app using Visual Studio as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net).)

Comment: In your .NET project, add a reference to the .winmd file to get access to the API: Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.15063.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract\1.0.0.0