# Error: "This application can only run in the context of an app container."

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I created a UWP app with desktop extensions and added the startup task as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#start-an-executable-file-when-users-log-into-windows). (I set `Executable="AutoStartupTest.exe"`.)

I logged off and logged on and got the error in the title, and don't know how to fix it because though it makes sense - why is it not in a container? This should happen automatically, no? The link is talking about a UWP app.

**EDIT**

The extension snippet as requested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849937/startuptask-class-is-not-recognized/45852552?noredirect=1#comment78686670_45852552).

```
<Extensions>
  <desktop:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="AutoStartupTest.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
    <desktop:StartupTask TaskId="someId" Enabled="true" DisplayName="Hi user!" />
  </desktop:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: I know the error is not very helpful. Is this a .NET executable? Try putting it in a subfolder and then reference it accordingly in the manifest, e.g. Executable="Win32\AutoStartupTest.exe". Let me know if this doesn't solve it.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT I was testing it on a regular UWP app. It seems that's impossible. I tried now with a Centennial app and it's working because it calls a .net exe which does not have to be executed in an app container. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It also works when the main app is UWP, and the startup task is a regular desktop EXE. Let me know if you can't get it to work and I will share a working sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StartupTask support for UWP processes is coming in the Fall Creators update later this year.

What you can do today is add a non-UWP EXE to your UWP package and reference that as StartupTask. Be sure to put it in a subfolder inside your package and reference it accordingly, e.g. Executable="Win32\AutoStartTest.exe". Also in this approach you will need to declare the 'runFullTrust' capability.