# UWP app fails to start on login using the StartupTask APIs

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge, windows-10-desktop

> **NOTE**: I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup) related question, this is *not* a duplicate

I'm working on a UWP app which also uses the Desktop Bridge (the app package contains the UWP app and a WinForms component), and I'm trying to add the auto startup feature, so far without success.

**Here's what I did:**

- Some research. Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup) question mentioned before, [this blog post from MS](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/#t33bKWWOeVAHo04E.97) and at the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask) as well.
- Followed the docs by editing the `Package.appxmanifest` file to add the `uap5` namespace, and then the `uap5:Extension` node as instructed, setting my app .exe file in the `Executable` property, and `Windows.FullTrustApplication` in the `EntryPoint` property.
- *Bonus*: just in case, I also tried to replace the `uap5` namespace with `desktop`, as some code samples used that one instead. Same result, the app doesn't start at all.
- Included the APIs to get the startup task and request it to be setup.
- Deployed the app, proceeded to use those APIs, got the confirm window and tapped "allow".
- Opened the Task Managed and double checked that the app name was there under the "Startup" tab, with the "Enabled" label correctly shown next to it.
- Logged out and back in

At this point nothing happens, except from the mouse pointer showing the loading ring for half a second after logging in. Opened the Windows event viewer and found an error, which was indicating the failed auto startup for the app. Tried again a few times and sure enough, every time the app didn't start and another identical error popped up in the event viewer. This is the error info:

```
Application name: <my app>.exe, versione: 1.0.0.0, timestamp: 0x5a68410c
Module: KERNELBASE.dll, versione: 10.0.17134.407, timestamp: 0x99042cc0
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Offset: 0x000000000003a388
Process ID: 0x1c4c
Path: C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\GitHub\<my app>\<my app>.Package\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\<my app>.exe
Module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
[...]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I've followed the docs step by step and I do see the app listed in the Task Manager, but it just fails to start this way.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: it seems the problem is related to the Desktop Bridge functionality. I have a UWP app and a packaging project, and I've added the startup task to both the `.appxmanifest` files (with different Ids). I do this as I use the packaging project to create the x86/x64 builds, and the UWP project directly for the ARM/ARM64 builds.

If I only deploy the UWP app (standalone, without the package) and enable the startup task, the app runs fine. But, if I deploy the packaging project and enable that startup task, the startup fails. I do see the startup task in the Task Manager in both cases. As mentioned earlier, when the startup task fails for the packaging project, I see those errors in the event viewer.

**EDIT #2**: did some more tests with the Desktop Bridge app. It seems that after it fails to start, the Windows event logger gets two more errors listed there for each attempt. One is the error in the "Application Error" category mentioned earlier, and another one is an error in the "AppModel-Runtime" category, with the following info:

> Failed with 0x490 modifying AppModel Runtime status for package  for user  (current status = 0x0, desired status = 0x20).

**EDIT #3**: as requested, here's the [`.appxmanifest` file](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/f5456348d902f6bae92462bbed694e78) for the packaging project. Note that as mentioned earlier, I tried adding the startup task both using the `desktop` namespace as well as the newer `uap5` namespace. Again, in both cases I can retrieve the task and prompt the user to enable it, and I do see it listed in the Task Manager, but the application still fails to start with the usual error.

Comment: Can you include the .net exception? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358376

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Hi, just tried crashing the app again, I'm not seeing any errors in the ".NET Runtime" source unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share your appxmanifest? Depending on whether you want to start your UWP component or your Winforms component as StartUp Task your will need to author the manifest extension differently.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Hi, I've added a new edit to my question with the full code for the `Package.appxmanifest` file, I hope it'll provide useful info. I always want to start the UWP app first, the Win32 component is just a small program I start after app finishes loading using the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` APIs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The way your manifest is written the StartupTask will attempt to start the Win32 component. If you want to start the UWP you will need to author the extension differently. Look at this doc in the section "UWP App startup task extension" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Well that worked, thank you so much!  I assumed the paragraph about UWP app startup was only meant for "standalone" UWP apps, with that extension in their own `.appxmanifest` file, it wasn't clear that it instead could be used in the package manifest as well. You can write that down as an answer if you want me to mark it as valid!

Comment: OK, good to hear you are unblocked now. I have posted this as answer here now, for the benefit of other who see this question in the future. Please mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up a StartupTask extension in your appxmanifest it is important to understand that the declaration is different for Win32 components vs UWP components. This is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask

UWP Components:

```
<Package xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5" ...>
...
<Applications>
    <Application ...>
        ...
        <Extensions>
          <uap5:Extension Category="windows.startupTask">
            <uap5:StartupTask
              TaskId="MyStartupId"
              Enabled="false"
              DisplayName="Test startup" />
          </uap5:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

Win32 Components:

```
<Package xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"...>
...
<Applications>
    <Application ...>
        ...
        <Extensions>
          <uap5:Extension
            Category="windows.startupTask"
            Executable="MyDesktopBridgeApp.exe"
            EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
            <uap5:StartupTask
              TaskId="MyStartupId"
              Enabled="false"
              DisplayName="My Desktop Bridge App" />
          </uap5:Extension>
        </Extensions>
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

Comment: Thanks again! This worked fine to start the UWP app, which then in turns starts the Win32 program by itself with the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` API, as mentioned earlier. I do want to suggest though that it might be a good idea to expand the docs a bit and maybe add a couple notes about packaged UWP apps like in this case. Currently, the docs only make the distinction between "standalone" UWP and Bridge apps, so the right location for the task declaration wasn't really clear. I get that the Desktop Bridge is primarily meant to be used the other way around (Win32 to UWP), but still.

Comment: Good feedback - in general our docs today don't cover "mixed" packages very well that contain both UWP and Win32 components. FYI - our docs also have the option at the bottom to submit direct feedback on the respective topic. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I've already opened a direct feedback on that `StartupTask` docs page a couple days ago, happy to help! 