# How to run Windows App SDK packaged C# app at startup?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I want to run my packaged c# app to start at log-in. Under the guidance of this post, I configured Package.appxmanifest and added relevant code to my app. However, when users log in, the splash screen appears but then the application fails to launch.

The post mentions one thing:

> If your app is enabled for startup activation, you should handle this
> case in your App class by overriding the OnActivated method.

However, WASDK app doesn't have an `OnActivated` method. I guess the problem lies here and I wonder how to correctly configure my code to fix this issue.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8236).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940683/uwp-app-start-automatically-at-startup

Comment: @HansPassant I've read this question and found no solutions. The accepted answer doesn't work for Windows App SDK app.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding True, the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.
According to [this blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/), we are supposed to write `package.appxmanifest` in this form:

```
<Extensions>
    <uap5:Extension
    Category="windows.startupTask"
    Executable="SingleInstancedError.exe"
    EntryPoint="SingleInstancedError.App">
        <uap5:StartupTask
        TaskId="SingleInstancedErrorId"
        Enabled="false"
        DisplayName="SingleInstancedError startup" />
    </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

However, to make it work for Windows App SDK, these two lines must be removed:

```
Executable="SingleInstancedError.exe"
EntryPoint="SingleInstancedError.App"
```

So that the manifest looks like this:

```
<Extensions>
    <uap5:Extension
    Category="windows.startupTask">
        <uap5:StartupTask
        TaskId="SingleInstancedErrorId"
        Enabled="false"
        DisplayName="SingleInstancedError startup" />
    </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

And the app runs normally at startup.